# How to automate already registered users scenario in Cypress

Tags: vue.js, cypress, ui-automation, cypress-intercept

I am new to Cypress and trying to automate this below-mentioned scenario using Cypress but I don't have an idea how to do it properly.

**Scenario** -: A user registers on a system using an email address and again trying to create another account using the same email address and getting and error saying "The email has already been taken"

below mentioned my test script.

```js
it("register same customer twice", function() {
  cy.intercept("POST", "**/api/register", {
    fixture: "already_used_email_registration_customer.json"
  });
  cy.visit("#/register");
  cy.get("#first-name").type("Test");
  cy.get("#last-name").type("Customer");
  cy.get("#email").type("teststage@gmail.com");
  cy.get('#user-dropdown').select('Buyer').should('have.value', '3');
  cy.get("#brand-name").type("TestC");
  cy.get("#password").type("testS1234@");
  cy.get("#confirm-password").type("testS1234@");
  cy.contains("I accept the Terms and Conditions.").click();
  cy.get("#register").click();
  cy.contains("The email has already been taken").should("exist");
  cy.hash().should("eq", "#/register");
});
```

I used a fixture file to this and instead of getting the error again the user gets registered to the system using the same email address. Does anyone know how to overcome this issue and how to automate this scenario using Cypress?

Comment: Hi. Wondering what `already_used_email_registration_customer.json` fixture contains? Does it contain the response api returns, or just a plain email? as from your code, you simply force the response to be whatever is in that fixture. Don't try to overwrite it with the fixture, just wait for the response and return the error message

Comment: I don't see any steps for the user to register the first time. Your test only shows what seems to be the second time registering with the same details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code looks good, there are two possible reasons why it's not working

- the `cy.intercept()` isn't matching the POST from the app.

  The Cypress runner should show you if this is the case. This [section of the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Command-Log) shows what that looks like.
- the fixture isn't responding in the way that app expects when the email is already registered. It's probably sending a particular `statusCode` - you can check what happens in a normal browser by looking at the Network tab.

  Use whatever statusCode you find occurs in this scenario in place of `xxx` in the following snippet:

  ```js
  cy.intercept("POST", "**/api/register", {
     statusCode: xxx,
     fixture: "already_used_email_registration_customer.json"
  })
  ```